# How to extract a value from an xml file with soap header using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, soap

i have multiple xml files and want to extract the content of a particular tag  using powershell. I tried the below but it doesnt seem to work:

first example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Include ('*.xml') | Foreach{

    [XML]$SOAP = Get-Content $_
 
    Write-Host $SOAP.Envelope.Body.Request.Batch.Reference
}
```

second example:

```
   [xml]$ret.Envelope.Body.Request.Batch.Reference.'#text'
```

sample xml as below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header></soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <v1:Request>
            <batch>
                <batchName>CPayments</batchName>
                <batchId>98754</batchId>
                <creationDate>2018-06-21T20:45:12</creationDate>
                <Reference>833511</Reference>
            </batch>
        </v1:Request>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Simply try `$ret.Envelope.Body.Request.Batch.Reference`

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text value of the `<Reference>` node, try something like this:

```
$items = Select-Xml -Xml $input -XPath '//*[local-name()="Reference"]/text()'
$items| Foreach {$_.Node.Value}
```

Output:

```
833511
```